# Import third party library in my component library error

Tags: vue.js, vite, draggable

I try to build a component library `vue3 + vite library mode`. And I use `vue.draggable.next` in my component library. All is good on development environment, but when I try to build it, and import my component library on other vue project, I have this error:

```
X [ERROR] No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"
node_modules/designer/dist/designer.js:1:7:
1 │ import kn, { reactive as qn, resolveComponent as Xt, openBlock as _t, createBlock as Ye, unref as _n, isRe...
```

- I want to know what is wrong with it.
- I have this error when I import my component library.

25/7
I think I've found the problem. The `designer` module must be main option in `package.json` like this.

```
"main": "dist/designer.umd.js",
```